# How to check if a category is a parent category ( Woocommerce )

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I wanted to add a test tag only to categories that have children categories. When i try to run this code, test tag is shown to every category. I'm using Woocommerce for this code. Thank you

```
<?php

$taxonomy     = 'product_cat';
  $orderby      = 'name';  
  $show_count   = 0;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
  $pad_counts   = 0;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
  $hierarchical = 1;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no  
  $title        = '';  
  $empty        = 0;

  $args = array(
         'taxonomy'     => $taxonomy,
         'orderby'      => $orderby,
         'show_count'   => $show_count,
         'pad_counts'   => $pad_counts,
         'hierarchical' => $hierarchical,
         'title_li'     => $title,
         'hide_empty'   => $empty
  );

 $all_categories = get_categories( $args );
 foreach ($all_categories as $cat) {
    if($cat->category_parent == 0) {
        $category_id = $cat->term_id;     
        echo '<li>';
        echo '<a href="'. get_term_link($cat->slug, 'product_cat') .'">'. $cat->name .'</a>';

        if($cat->category_parent == 0) {
          echo 'test';
        }

        echo '</li>';
    }      
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

`get_categories` return array of [WP_Term](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_term/) which does not contain `category_parent` member. As it null, `null == 0` returns true and you condition is always true. Replace it with `$cat->parent`.

Also you can specify `parent` parameter in your `get_categories`, and skip this check.

```
$args = array(
 ...
 'parent' => 0, // get only top level categories
 ...
);
```